# Tie breaking in a priority queue using python

Tags: python, algorithm, priority-queue

I'm using a heap queue to implement an algorithm, when i add new nodes to my queue, they're sorted by a heuristic function: eg heappush(queue, (score(node), node)), which is fantastic, apart from the fact that when I come to pop the next node out of the queue, i want the most recently added node, as opposed to the first added node, which is what heappop returns. how can I get the most recent nodes added to the queue without breaking it?

I guess I could just begin iteration at the first element, and while the next element has the same score, continue. Then when I find the final element with that score, I select it and remove it from the list. This obviously isn't very efficient though and breaks the time complexity of a priority queue?

I'm stuck on this and I can't figure out a way to do it.

Thanks.

edit; Using a counter, as suggested will not work (perhaps I've misunderstood)

```
>>> queue = []
>>> heappush(queue, (2, 0, 'a'))
>>> heappush(queue, (3, -1, 'b'))
>>> queue
[(2, 0, 'a'), (3, -1, 'b')]
>>> heappush(queue, (2, -2, 'c'))
>>> queue
[(2, -2, 'c'), (3, -1, 'b'), (2, 0, 'a')]
```

Now the queue is ordered incorrectly, and 'b' which is a worse option than 'a' is placed before it.

EDIT 2:

What the hell?

```
>>> heappop(queue)
(2, -2, 'c')
>>> queue
[(2, 0, 'a'), (3, -1, 'b')]
>>>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

One very simple way is to add a middle term containing a timestamp or a counter value. So for example:

```
>>> heap = []
>>> counter = itertools.count()
>>> for i in range(10):
...     heapq.heappush(heap, (i, -next(counter), str(i) + ' oldest'))
...     heapq.heappush(heap, (i, -next(counter), str(i) + ' newest'))
... 
>>> heapq.heappop(heap)
(0, -1, '0 newest')
>>> heapq.heappop(heap)
(0, 0, '0 oldest')
>>> heapq.heappop(heap)
(1, -3, '1 newest')
>>> heapq.heappop(heap)
(1, -2, '1 oldest')
```

As agf mentions, this is the approach used by the [`heapq`](http://docs.python.org/library/heapq.html#priority-queue-implementation-notes) docs, only using negative indices. (The implementation there also includes a nice task-removal and priority-change routine.)

Comment: This is specifically mentioned as the solution under [Priority Queue Implementation](http://docs.python.org/library/heapq.html#priority-queue-implementation-notes) in the `heapq` docs.

Comment: I've edited my original post to demonstrate an example of why I think this might not work, perhaps I've misunderstood what you're suggesting?

Comment: @user1291204 A heap queue isn't a sorted list. It's partially sorted, such that `(heap[k] <= heap[2*k+1]) and (heap[k] <= heap[2*k+2])`, the heap invariant, is always `True`. So `heap[1]` doesn't have to be less than or equal to `heap[2]`, just `heap[3]` and higher. `heap[0]` will always be the smallest item.